# Dropdown in cell angular grid Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ag-grid

I have a angular 7 ag-Grid with a drop inside my cell. My dropdown  works            fine but it doesn't work for the table last record ag table hide dropdown inside inside table. Down below a screenshot and my css is attached.

**css:**

```
.ag-cell {     overflow:visible;    }
       .ag-row {
        z-index: 0;   }
       .ag-row.ag-row-focus {
        z-index: 1;   }   .ag-root.ag-layout-auto-height,   
       .ag-body-viewport.ag-layout-auto-height,     
       .ag-body-viewport-wrapper.ag-layout-auto-height {
        overflow: visible;   }
```

**screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its not a proper solution but a hack

Try below, i implemented this solution for the same scenario for `material-date-picker`

As drop down is `absolute` by default so set it to `fixed` make it independent form parent.

```
 .drop-down { 
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
}
```

> Change the class as its is in angular 7 dropdown here i give an
>   example

OR

> You can set `overflow:auto` to parent table wrapper